# Generating expression string in SQL to add values of a column in pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I want to get this string for using in my other queries

```
@cols = 'ISNULL(myColumnName_value_1,0) + ISNULL(myColumnName_value_2,0) + ... + ISNULL(myColumnName_value_N,0)'
```

and `myColumnName_value_1` OR`myColumnName_value_2` , ... which could be anything.

And my query is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ' + ISNULL(' + (c.myColumnName) +',0)'
        FROM myTableName c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

print @cols
```

but I can't get what I want.

my desired output of print:

```
ISNULL(myColumnName_value_1,0) + 
ISNULL(myColumnName_value_2,0) + ... + 
ISNULL(myColumnName_value_N,0)
```

And `...` because I don't know the name or number of columns.

Comment: AS I said above I want this output : ISNULL(myColumnName_value_1,0) + ISNULL(myColumnName_value_2,0) + ... + ISNULL(myColumnName_value_N,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your modified query.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ' + ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.myColumnName) +',0)'
        FROM myTableName c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,2,1,'')

print @cols
```

Comment: But why you want to concat all these columns ? I guess you are trying to achieve dynamic pivoting.

Comment: yes. I want to get sum of dynamic columns for each row in new column.